# Locations of Empty Bottles in Wind Waker?

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

Alright, so I'm looking for Empty Bottles in *LoZ: Wind Waker*. I've already found the first 2 from Medli and the Eskimo dude's assistant, but I'm having trouble finding the rest, and I'm assuming there are only 2 more judging by the fact that those are the only 2 empty spaces left in my inventory. So I would be really thankful if someone could tell me the locations and how to get these empty bottles.

Comment: Zelda question! as soon as I saw it the music started playing in my head :3

Comment: @hammythepig Same here, that game was legendary. It's music, it's gameplay and story. It was just awesome!

Comment: @hammythepig Heh, I didn't even realize I was humming the Deku Tree music til I saw your comment!

Comment: Agreed, just seeing anything Zelda-related puts me in a good mood.  I actually restarted Wind Waker recently with the intention of playing through it again.  Ahem... anyway, with regards to the answer, PileOfDuty's is complete and correct, so really nothing to contribute here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gamecube/469050-the-legend-of-zelda-the-wind-waker/faqs/20853):

## Bottle 1

```
Location:      Dragon Roost Island
Items Needed:  None
```

You get this bottle automatically from Medli when you help 
her into the shrine. You can't progress in the game without it.

## Bottle 2

```
Location:      Bomb Island
Items Needed:  None
```

This bottle is in an Enemy submarine near Bomb island. Get onto the 
island and you should find a guy in white with a telescope, going 
"Whoah!" at whatever he's looking at. Use the telescope, and he 
should be looking at a submarine with 1 raft attached to it. Go 
inside the submarine, pick off the enemies, and a chest should 
appear with the 2nd bottle inside.

## Bottle 3

```
Location:      Rock Spire Isle
Items Needed:  500 rupees (so rupee bag upgrade from A3 or G2)
```

Sometime after you get the bombs, Beedle will be sending you a RED
Beedle Map (advertising his new bomb stock), detailing all the places 
he will be appearing in. On the RED map, there should be 1 face 
that is Beedle's, but with a helmet on. There, he'll be selling
a bottle (500 rupees), a heart piece (950 rupees) and a treasure map 
(900 rupees).

## Bottle 4

```
Location:      Windfall Island
Items Needed:  None
```

Get this from the blond girl who was held captive at the Forsaken Fortress along with your sister and a brunette (obviously, this cannot 
be done until after you've rescued your sister). By day, she will 
be working near the Eskimo's store; by night, she will be snooping 
around near the auction house. Talk to her, and she will order you 
to go away. Do so, and she will sneak off. After that it's a game 
of stealth.

Follow her around Windfall, careful to keep out of her sight (she turns 
around every now and then to check), until you find her trying to 
crank the safe in the Eskimo's store. Catch her in the act, and she 
will tell you her sob story and ask you to let her go. Refuse, 
tell her it's wrong, and she will then see the light and thank you. 
She will give you the 4th bottle if you get this sequence right. If 
not, you can always redo the quest by going in and out of a building; 
she should be there every time if you haven't gotten the bottle.